# Why am I getting a invalid syntax on this call method? Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that can delete a file with Python. When I moved the file to my startup directory with my script, a lot of the code was changed, not by me. I've just assumed this was normal and continued trying to make it delete a file on startup. I later realized it wasn't working because one of the call methods kept getting an invalid syntax. Here's my code.

Python Version: 3.8.7

Error message is :
`invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 7)`

```py
LOAD_CONST(0), LOAD_CONST(None), IMPORT_NAME(os), STORE_NAME(os)
LOAD_CONST(0), LOAD_CONST(None), IMPORT_NAME(shutil), STORE_NAME(shutil)

source = 'C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\startup.py'
destination = 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'

LOAD_NAME(shutil), LOAD_METHOD(move), LOAD_NAME(source), LOAD_NAME(destination), CALL_METHOD[2], STORE_NAME(new_path)

print(new_path)


LOAD_NAME(os), LOAD_METHOD(remove), LOAD_CONST('C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Desktop/delete.txt'), CALL_METHOD[1], POP_TOP
print('File Removed!'), return None
```

Comment: The `return` after the comma `,` causes the error. But though all the rest can be valid Python syntax, all of this just doesn't look like Python code. Some parts look like bits of disassembled bytecode - where does this mess come from??

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. If you want to delete a file, you can use the `os` module in python. For example:

```
import os
os.remove("/some/file/path/to/remove.txt")
```